# Get a Soap request

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

Let me explain, I am doing something like a webservice in which I get information from a platform called Wialon, they use a section called repeaters where they send me a SOAP request to a specific address, I will be honest I have no idea how to use SOAP i never did something like this, so my question is how can i receive that SOAP data in PHP, so I can see it, I want to receive that SOAP request and i don't know save it in DB to see how it works or the structure, because these guys of wialon do not give information about what they send in that soap but I imagine it is an xml, so far I have tried to investigate but the truth is I do not know how soap works, im using this code that I found:

```
class MyClass {

    public function helloWorld() {
        require_once 'com.sine.controlador/Controlador.php';
        $c = new Controlador();
        $xml = $c->insertarResultado('06',func_get_args());
        return 'Hello Welt ' . print_r(func_get_args(), true);
    }

}

try {
    $server = new SOAPServer(
            NULL, array(
        'uri' => 'http://localhost/WebserviceGLMS2/index.php'
            )
    );

    $server->setClass('MyClass');
    $server->handle();
} catch (SOAPFault $f) {
    print $f->faultstring;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work, hope you can help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A soap request is nothing else than a xml post request. In PHP you can get the whole request body with the following code.

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($content);
```

You can use this unless it 's not `multipart/formdata`.

Comment: it worked, hahaha, thanks now i can work from that thank you